# How to create a table to display relative frequencies of selected words (eg. with, can, will) from any text corpus in nltk package in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, machine-learning-model, nltk

Interested words are ['with', 'can', 'will']
`gutenberg` corpus is the corpus we would like to search on.

Expected output is

```
                           can  could    may  might should   will  would 
        austen-emma.txt    270    825    213    322    366    559    815 
  austen-persuasion.txt    100    444     87    166    185    162    351 
       austen-sense.txt    206    568    169    215    228    354    507 
          bible-kjv.txt    213    165   1024    475    768   3807    443 
        blake-poems.txt     20      3      5      2      6      3      3 
     bryant-stories.txt     75    154     18     23     38    144    110 
burgess-busterbrown.txt     23     56      3     17     13     19     46 
      carroll-alice.txt     57     73     11     28     27     24     70 
    chesterton-ball.txt    131    117     90     69     75    198    139 
   chesterton-brown.txt    126    170     47     71     56    111    132 
chesterton-thursday.txt    117    148     56     71     54    109    116 
  edgeworth-parents.txt    340    420    160    127    271    517    503 
 melville-moby_dick.txt    220    215    230    183    181    379    421 
    milton-paradise.txt    107     62    116     98     55    161     49 
 shakespeare-caesar.txt     16     18     35     12     38    129     40 
 shakespeare-hamlet.txt     33     26     56     28     52    131     60 
shakespeare-macbeth.txt     21     15     30      5     41     62     42 
     whitman-leaves.txt     88     49     85     26     42    261     85
```

Reference: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

Answer (score 0):

Finding frequency of words for the Gutenberg Corpus. You need to just put Gutenberg text files as input.

> ```
> cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
>     (fileids, word)
>     for fileids in gutenberg.fileids()
>     for word in gutenberg.words(fileids))
> modals = ['with', 'can', 'will']
> cfd.tabulate(fileids, samples=modals)
> ```

Output :

```
                        with  can will 
        austen-emma.txt 1187  270  559 
  austen-persuasion.txt  643  100  162 
       austen-sense.txt  971  206  354 
          bible-kjv.txt 5961  213 3807 
        blake-poems.txt   59   20    3 
     bryant-stories.txt  276   75  144 
burgess-busterbrown.txt   59   23   19 
      carroll-alice.txt  175   57   24 
    chesterton-ball.txt  799  131  198 
   chesterton-brown.txt  726  126  111 
chesterton-thursday.txt  544  117  109 
  edgeworth-parents.txt 1304  340  517 
 melville-moby_dick.txt 1659  220  379 
    milton-paradise.txt  876  107  161 
 shakespeare-caesar.txt  131   16  129 
 shakespeare-hamlet.txt  212   33  131 
shakespeare-macbeth.txt  134   21   62 
     whitman-leaves.txt 1111   88  261
```

Hope This answers your question :)